# Ruby strings that appear the same are not equal, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am importing a CSV and creating rows using ActiveRecord. The CSV is:

```
first_name,middle_name,last_name,degrees,email,induction_year (ie 2017),"induction_type (options: alumni, associate, faculty, honorary, student)"
John,Middle,Doe,"BA, MPH",test@test.com,2017,alumni
```

My method to import looks something like this:

```
def import
  CSV.foreach(@file.path, headers: true, header_converters: lambda {|field| field.partition(" ").first }, col_sep: ',') do |row|
    member_params = row.to_hash
    Member.create!(member_params)
  end
end
```

But it throws `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'first_name' for Member.` Edit: It's not a problem with Member I can create Member as you would expect with something like `Member.create!(first_name: 'test')`

Open up a pry and I get this feedback:

```
[1] pry(#<InducteesUpload>)> member_params
=> {"first_name"=>"John",
"middle_name"=>"Middle",
"last_name"=>"Doe",
"degrees"=>"BA, MPH",
"email"=>"test@test.com",
"induction_year"=>"2017",
"induction_type"=>"alumni"}
[2] pry(#<InducteesUpload>)> member_params.keys.first == "first_name"
 => false
[3] pry(#<InducteesUpload>)> member_params.keys.first.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Adding more:

```
[1] pry(#<InducteesUpload>)> member_params.keys
=> ["first_name",
  "middle_name",
  "last_name",
  "degrees",
  "email",
  "induction_year",
  "induction_type"]

[2] pry(#<InducteesUpload>)> member_params["first_name"] = "test"
=> "test"
[3] pry(#<InducteesUpload>)> member_params
=> {"first_name"=>"John",
 "middle_name"=>"Middle",
 "last_name"=>"Doe",
 "degrees"=>"BA, MPH",
 "email"=>"test@test.com",
 "induction_year"=>"2017",
 "induction_type"=>"alumni",
 "first_name"=>"test"}
```

It's not a problem with Member as can you see with the above weirdness. But will post if it you really want.

So problem is revealed here:

```
[6] pry(#<InducteesUpload>)> member_params.keys.first.bytes
=> [239, 187, 191, 102, 105, 114, 115, 116, 95, 110, 97, 109, 101]
[7] pry(#<InducteesUpload>)> "first_name".bytes
=> [102, 105, 114, 115, 116, 95, 110, 97, 109, 101]
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `Member`?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with Member... Usually it would need to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` if you are trying to save to the database.

Comment: What's the result of `member_params.keys`?

Comment: Maybe you have some invisible characters in the "first_name" key...

Comment: Edited to show more stuff. Not a problem with Member

Comment: what is `member_params.class`?

Comment: member_params.class is Hash

Comment: I'm betting on unicode magic. Compare `member_params.keys.first.bytes` and `"first_name".bytes`

Comment: Yeah you're right @SergioTulentsev do you want to put that in as an answer?

Comment: Any resources you can point to to learn how that works?

Comment: @swaincreates: how what works? Unicode?

Comment: @swaincreates the first three bytes (239 187 191) form a UTF-8 [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Try setting the [IO encoding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Encoding) to `BOM|UTF-8` to have Ruby strip the BOM automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting on unicode magic. Compare `member_params.keys.first.bytes` and `"first_name".bytes`. You're likely to find a difference.

Unicode has a lot of symbols that look alike, but are not equal to each other.

Comment: Speaking of symbols: `codepoints` is usually more meaningful than `bytes` when dealing with multibyte strings.

Comment: @Stefan: generally yes, but in this case `bytes` works just as well, I think. Or maybe even better! (BOM is not a valid codepoint, is it?)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're having a conflict between strings and symbols as your hash key. Try `Member.create!(member_params.with_indifferent_access)` as mentioned [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html).

Comment: Gave it a shot, but that didn't work. And as you can see above the keys are all strings.